# Resources returns a Drawable of the wrong type

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have an app with three `ProgressBars`, each with its own custom progress `Drawable`. These Drawables are fairly straightforward- each is a `LayerDrawable` with a transparent background layer, a transparent secondary progress layer, and a solid color progress layer.

All three `ProgressBars` are displayed in the same layout.

The issue I started running into is that one of these `ProgressBars` is not displaying correctly- it simply does not display any progress. This only occurs on some devices (confirmed on a emulated Nexus One running 2.3.3 and a Galaxy SII running 4.1.2).

I put a breakpoint in `onCreate`, and discovered that the first two `ProgressBars` have their `mProgressDrawable` property correctly set to a `LayerDrawable`, but the third is set to a `ColorDrawable`.

Sure enough, the following code returns two `LayerDrawables` and one `ColorDrawable`:

```
    Drawable blueDrawable  = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_blue);
    Drawable redDrawable   = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_red);
    Drawable greenDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_green);
```

No matter where I move the third `ProgressBar` in the layout and in the code, or try to swap around the `progressDrawable` attributes, the one referencing my third XML `Drawable` displays no progress and gives me a `ColorDrawable`.

Interestingly, I discovered that simply creating a new XML file in my drawable folder fixes the problem. This leads me to believe that there is an issue with the way that Android is packaging or loading my resources, but I am having trouble figuring out how to identify and correct the root problem.

I also cannot reproduce the problem in a new application.

How can I continue tracking down the source of this problem?

**`progressDrawable` XML:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/myapp_green" />
                <!-- The other two drawbles only change this color -->
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**colors.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <color name="myapp_red">#dd514c</color>
    <color name="myapp_green">#5eb95e</color>
    <color name="myapp_blue">#0e90d2</color>
</resources>
```

**Update from moving the `progressDrawable` attributes around**

- red, blue, green: 3rd is broken
- red, green, green: 2nd and 3rd are broken
- blue, green, red: 2nd is broken
- blue, red, blue: all work
- green, green, green: all work
- green, green, red: all work
- green, blue, red: all work

Comment: Can you post the three separate drawable xml files?

Comment: Sure, they are [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9467827)

Comment: Is there a typo anywherre in the definition of myapp_green?

Comment: I don't believe so. I've added colors.xml to my post. As per my comments on the answer below, this still occurs when I switch the color from green to another color.

Comment: " also cannot reproduce the problem in a new application."

can we rule out project build / resource id issues? have you tried to clean the project / refresh the drawables directory (right click->refresh) I've had some X-files issues like these that got magically solved....

Comment: also it would help to see the progressbars layout xml / instantiation code itself, the issue has to be there

Comment: Does a duplicate progress_green.xml perhaps exist in one of the density-specific drawable folders?

Comment: @rupps Yes, I have tried cleaning and refreshing. I linked to all three layouts in my comment above. I don't instantiate the drawables myself; they are used as the `android:progressDrawable` of ProgressBars defined in XML.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Nope. These three drawables exist only in /res/drawable.

Comment: @Tanis can you please post or link the XML that defines the progressbars with the drawables? Looks like it's the only stone unturned by our side... I will try to build a layout with it.

Comment: @Tanis, does the progressbar show correctly in the IDE preview? If you set any of the working progressbars so they use the drawable the non-working progressbar has, do they show correctly?

Comment: The layout with the ProgressBars can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/tanis7x/9740484). The ProgressBars show up fine in the IDE (and on most devices). I've updated my post with the results of trying to move the `progressDrawable` attributes around. The green drawable seems to work fine if it is the first one, but is broken if it is the second or third.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the order, from:

```
Drawable blueDrawable  = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_blue);
Drawable redDrawable   = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_red);
Drawable greenDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_green);
```

to for example:

```
Drawable redDrawable   = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_red);
Drawable greenDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_green);
Drawable blueDrawable  = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_blue);
```

is than still the greenDrawable the problem or still the 3rd position (blueDrawable)?

Comment: what happens if you change the:

     <solid android:color="@color/myapp_green" />

to a color that you use in an other progressDrawable.
Still an error?

Comment: Same result- no color on that ProgressBar, and it still shows up as a ColorDrawable instead of a LayerDrawable

Comment: .... i ve still no explanation... the only thing i think can be wrong is something in your xml that we dont see...

Comment: I was definitely leaning towards that as well, but a diff on those three files shows that only the color references are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't even see the progress bar, maybe you have a light background stuck somewhere?

Try to set the style attribute to:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
```